# Python merges lines when reading line by line?

Tags: python, json, filereader

I have a file in which I have written with `json.dumps(tweet)` on each line (around 300000 lines). The code writing the lines is:

```
for tweet in collection:
    outputfile.write(json.dumps(tweet)+"\n")
    written_tweets += 1
```

The file looks great, exactly what I need:

One sample line looks like (all of the look the same -- checked fact):

```
{"url": "http://youtu.be/F4pkpyRFLgA?a", "text": "I liked a @YouTube video Spoopy foxy Halloween", "screen_name": "placiboeffect", "id": 9255295       90155661313, "time": "Wed Nov 01 01:07:04 +0000 2017"}
```

Then in another python script I am trying to use this file, read the lines one by one and clean them (not important). I am doing this with:

```
      lines = open(self.input_file, 'r').read().splitlines()
      content = []
      faulty_lines = 0
      for line in lines:
          line = line.replace('\\"', '\\\"')
          try:
             content.append(json.loads(line))
          except Exception as e:
              faulty_lines += 1
              print (line)
              raise e
```

The json.loads fails for some lines (around 1000-2000) per file and when analysing the line, I got a weird line, a combination of 2 lines existent in my file e.g.:

```
{"url": "http://youtu.be/mI7XX{"url": "http://youtu.be/fLU8eksPyyE?a", "text": "I liked a @YouTube video WHERE WILL BLEDSOE BE TRADED? 7 POSSIBLE TRADES!", "screen_name": "WTS2323", "id": 925529722926370816, "time": "Wed Nov 01 01:07:36 +0000 2017"}
```

It is kinda weirdly merging 2 lines and of course json.loads fails. I was able to find parts of this combined tweet in my file.

Note: I tried multiple strategies of reading:

```
with open(self.input_file) as f:
     for line in f:
         /*do whatever*/
```

or

```
lines = open(self.input_file).readlines()
lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
```

and others. I always get this weird combined tweets. Can someone help me find out why this happens??

Update: the lines that get merged are:

```
{"url": "http://youtu.be/fLU8eksPyyE?a", "text": "I liked a @YouTube video  WHERE WILL BLEDSOE BE TRADED? 7 POSSIBLE TRADES!", "screen_name": "WT       S2323", "id": 925529722926370816, "time": "Wed Nov 01 01:07:36 +0000 2017"}
```

and

```
{"url": "http://youtu.be/mI7XXoSHHg4?a", "text": "I liked a @YouTube video  Dat $tick - Rich Chigga (ACOUSTIC COVER)", "screen_name": "rifqihahay       ", "id": 925529589903962119, "time": "Wed Nov 01 01:07:04 +0000 2017"}
```

Comment: Can you post the two lines from the input file that are merged together when reading?

Comment: one of them: {"url": "http://youtu.be/mI7XXoSHHg4?a", "text": "I liked a video Dat $tick - Rich Chigga (ACOUSTIC COVER)", "screen_name": "rifqihahay       ", "id": 925529589903962119, "time": "Wed Nov 01 01:07:04 +0000 2017"}   second: {"url": "http://youtu.be/fLU8eksPyyE?a", "text": "I liked a video WHERE WILL BLEDSOE BE TRADED? 7 POSSIBLE TRADES!", "screen_name": "WT       S2323", "id": 925529722926370816, "time": "Wed Nov 01 01:07:36 +0000 2017"}
They are not even one after another in the main file!!!

Comment: Post both lines that get merged (and add them to the question please comments are messy for keeping formatting)

Comment: I don't see how this could happen given that each line is a valid json object. So perhaps they're not after all? Also, the replace does nothing, the old/new strings are identical. (And what is it supposed to accomplish anyway?)

Comment: I put the replace as a safety measure in case of escape chars.

Comment: What you wrote with json.dumps will be readable by json.loads. And as said, you're not changing the string, you're just copying it. The file is probably the issue, if python reads such a line, then there's probably such a line in the file.